# How do I use modifiers to make this irregular shaped torus?

Tags: modifiers, shape-keys, glass, curve-modifier

I'm a newbie to blender and want to make this irregular shape but in 3d. [image]

I started with a torus but I have only gotten this far. I wasn't able to get the exact shape and then got stuck trying to move the minor circle off center.

[image]

I'm planning on making it look like a glass sculpture--I've nailed how to make it look like glass but can't get the actually shape right! Please help!!

Thank you!!

Comment: Hello, follow the shapes with some extrusions? Also how do you want to do it in 3D, is it supposed to be flat like a painter's palette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is what you mean but if you want it to be a torus then I assume you want the profile to be a circle all around it but with different thickness?
If so you could do it like this:
[image]
Start with a mesh circle, the amount of vertices will dictate how much variation in thickness there is.

Then convert it into a curve in the Object->Convert To->Curve Menu
[image]
Now that it's a curve, spawn another curve circle and move it's origin to one of the vertices so it's on the outside. Use this curve circle as the Bevel Object for the curve that you converted. Do this in the Curve tab on the right:
[image]
This will give you a torus where the inner whole doesn't stop being a circle if you change the radius of the points.
Now you can select a point and hit Alt+S to make the radius bigger. If you have proportional Editing active as seen on the first picture, the change in radius will smooth out the other vertices.
Then you can add a subdivision modifier to it to make it smooth